# Applying options by default to an Excel spreadsheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, templates, default-settings

I am given an excel spreadsheet with some defined formatting over which I have no control. Upon my user opening the spreadsheet in MS Excel, I want some formatting options which are not currently defaulted to be applied to the spreadsheet. Specifically, what I'm looking for is the following:

- Switch from portrait to landscape mode
- Upon printing, scale horizontally to fit on one page (wide)

What I have already thought of, and why I wasn't able to make that work, are as follows:

- modifying some application or registry settings to make these options selected by default for all spreadsheets in MS Excel. I have looked into this and have not found a way to set global settings in MS Excel. Can you and, if so, how?
- defining a template and having it applied to all spreadsheets in Excel or, possibly, just to ones which I define automatically somehow. I read something about modifying a spreadsheet in the Excel install directory but didn't get much farther than this. Is this the path I should be going down?
- some sort of macro or VBA thingy I can write and push to users' systems which auto-executes upon opening spreadsheets. I have looked into this but it seems that macros are tied to specific documents and/or templates and that you can't just write a macro that can be executed against any document. If you can do such a thing, an answer that briefly outlines how to do so would be accepted.
- some new bespoke program whose only function is to print our Excel spreadsheets using the proper formatting. We can definitely do this but it would seem to require the most work and/or getting the users to learn new things which we would like to avoid.

Other methods of solution are fine, as long as they require almost no end-user knowledge beyond basic Excel usage. Some examples of things we don't want to do are the following:

- Require users to apply the appropriate formatting before printing. This would apparently be too easy of a solution and our betters want us to have to work for our money.
- A new option or feature that would require the users learn something new to print out the spreadsheets correctly. The client doesn't pay its employees enough to expect them to learn new things.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Like other Stack Exchange sites, this is a Q&A site for you to ask specific questions when you have attempted something and get stuck. It is not service site where you can layout your demands to wait for us to take care of it for you. Please read ***[ask]***, then add details of what you have already attempted and where you are stuck.

Comment: "I am given an excel spreadsheet" - do you have already files for which you want to apply formatting, or do you want your settings to be applied for all new workbooks? Have you tried using templates?

Comment: @CharlieRB Edited a section to make it clearer what I had already considered and (partially) tried. Please let me know if you think more details are required there or otherwise please feel free to clean up the comments. Thanks

Comment: A Macro or VBA solution could be set up to be exicuted on other documents. All the end user will need to do; is open the file that contains the Macro or VBA.

Comment: If you do this for business, it pays to invest in learning VBA. It will help a lot. You can do with it almost everything.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out a solution that can work for us: we can use an Excel add-in.

We implement a handler for the Application's WorkbookOpen event and set the active sheet's page setup as follows:

- Orientation: landscape
- Zoom: false
- FitToPagesWide: 1
- FitToPagesTall: false

This causes the printed spreadsheet to be in landscape mode and fit all columns on one page by default with no extra user interaction.